# Accessing an asp.net api which uses AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect from postman

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication, postman, openid-connect

I created an asp.net core api which uses openIdConnect library to authenticate users using Azure AD and it works fine when I test it from the browser but when I try to test the api from post man by generating an access token and use it to access the api, the response is a redirect to login page indicating that I am unaouthorized, so how can I access the api from postman[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQiaY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding Jwt bearer authentication to `ConfigureServices` in my `startup.cs` and decorates the controller with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` so if I am trying to access the api from the browser it will use the openIdConnect scheme, else it will use the jwt scheme